# Excel, Needed: Automatic repeat after data entered, unless manually changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

MS Excel, one row of data (numbers 1 to 20). All cells input is done by a drop-lists.

I wonder if it is possible to choose a drop-down list element and all cells to its right within the range, automatically copies the applied data.

For example, I choose in Cell A1 - (3), and all 20 cells (A1 to T1) become (3), then I change the data in Cell E to enter (7), and now I should have cells A1 to D1 showing (3), and Cells E1 to T1 showing (7).

Would that be possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with VBA. Whether or not the cells have data validation does not matter.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:T1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range(Target, "T1") = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Copy the code, right-click the sheet tab, select "View Code" and paste the code into the code window. You need to save the file as a macro-enabled file with the xlsm extension.